# Should I join features and targets dataframes for use with scikit-learn?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to create a regression model to predict deliverables (dataframe 2) using design parameters (dataframe 1). Both dataframes have a id number that I used as an index.

Is it possible to use two dataframes to create a dataset for sklearn? Or do I need to join them? If I need to join them then what would be the best way?

```
# import data 
df1= pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name='Data1',index_col='Unnamed: 0')
df2= pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name='Data2',index_col='Unnamed: 0')
```

I have only used sklearn on a single dataframe that had all of the columns for the feature and target vectors in it. So not sure how to handle the case where I am using two dataframes where one has the features and one has the targets.

Comment: Your title is not very clear. Can you be more presiced, so the one who wants to answer knows what this is about?

Answer (score 0):

All estimators in scikit-learn have a signature like `estimator.fit(X, y)`, `X` being training features and `y` training targets.

Then, prediction will be achieved by calling some kind of `estimator.predict(X_test)`, with `X_test` being the test features.

Even [`train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) takes as parameters two arrays `X` and `y`.

This means that, as long as you maintain the right order in rows, nothing requires you to merge features and targets.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I just spot checked the data and it looks like the rows line up nicely. Just to be safe, I could sort them based on the index? The Well IDs are numbers that go from like 1 to 1500+.

Answer (score 0):

Completely agree with the *Guillaume* answer.

Just be aware, as he said, of **the rows order**. That's the key of your problem. If they have the same order, you don't need to merge dataframe and you can `fit` the model directly.

But, if they are not in the same order, you have to combine both dataframes (*similar to left join in SQL*) in order to relate features and targets of one ID. You can do it like this (more information [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html)):

```
df_final= pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

As you used the ID as index, it should work properly. Be aware that maybe `NaN` values will appear if some ID appears in one Dataframe but not in the other one. You will have to handle with them.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Looks like the rows line up nicely. Appreciate the help!